# replacing image in twig/symfony template: not working properly

Tags: symfony, twig

So I want to replace the company logo. These are what i tried:

1. copy new image to the images folder and change the img tag to reference to the new logo.
2. make the new logo filename same as the old filename. delete the old logo and put the new one in it's place

my problem is that when I change tried the 2 things above, the new logo is displayed like it's been zoomed in. It's weird since the width and height parameters are used in the img tag.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**Some info:**

This is the html inside in the twig that references the company logo. This is the one before I started my edits.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.mycompany.com" title="Buy from us" rel="home" target="_blank">{% image "@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/our-company-logo.png" %}<img src="{{ asset_url }}" width="214" height="45" alt="Flinders logo">{% endimage %}</a>
</div>
```

notes:

1. I'm running symfony in dev mode
2. I cleared my symfony cache
3. I dumped my assets (php app/console assetic:dump) just in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Try using the browsers Dev Tool to check where the "zoomed in" effect comes from. Toggle the Dev Tool with F12 or in Chrome you can also right click on the element and click on the last element saying "Inspect element". This will open the Dev Toolbar and auto select the div (if there are no other divs above it. In this case you have to manually click on the correct div inside the toolbar). In the toolbar itself you can also see the CSS on the right side. First check if the width/height properties are the same as in the image tag or if these parameters are still on the image tag or removed.

Comment: Before trying other things, clear your browser cache and make sure you are testing in dev, or clear production cache to be safe. However, I assume that is not the problem, I wonder though why you don't store images in the web folder, Twigs asset digs in the web folder so it's a great place to store images, just make a media folder and place your images there. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

why not use it as a background image inside the nav-brand css class and with property of background-position cover or something like that?